# Auto generate client for Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring

TL;DR: auto generate HTTP client for each REST Spring Controller to reuse in other services written with Spring.

When working with multiple micro-services that are written with spring I find myself rewriting the client for each controller. Lets say I write a controller in service X:

```
@RestController
public class SubscriptionController {

    @Autowired
    private SubscriptionService subscriptionService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/subscription", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public SubscriptionDTO getMySubscription() {
        return subscriptionService.getCurrentUserSubscription();
    }

}
```

I will import the DTO in service Y, write HTTP request to the mapping defined in the other service, and write tests for it.

```
@Service
public class SubscriptionApiService {

    @Autowired
    private HttpClient httpClinet;

    public SubscriptionDTO getMySubscription() {
        return httpClient.get("/subscription", SubscriptionDTO.class);
    }

}
```

It's very a repetitive process, and I'm quite sure someone already wrote a library to automate this process. However I was unable to find anything like that. Any idea?

Comment: Swagger has a http client generator. You should check it

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `Swagger2`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application extends SpringApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

You can access `Swagger2` html by this url: `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`

I also `@ComponentScan` my packages and these are the `dependencies` needed for `Swagger2`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I'm looking for the code generation, just like nowszy94 suggested, however his suggestion with swagger does not look too straight forward.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought you just want to use `Swagger2` and you are running a `SpringBootApplication`